# How to use domain open website directly without port number?

Tags: spring-boot, web, nginx, server

I'm new to web and internet. and now I meet a problem that I can't remove the port number after the domain name after I follow the way from internet to configure Nginx

I resolved external IP address by GoDaddy.com

```
server {
    listen       8080 default_server;
    listen       [::]:8080 default_server;
    server_name  www.gogogo.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    location ~ .*\.   
(js|css|img|jpg|svg|gif|png|bmp|swf|ttf|woff|svg|map|eot)$ {
    root /gogogo/src/main/webapp;
    }
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
(following is from godaddy.com)
Type    Name        Value           TTL
 A           @   33.231.62.143      600 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify a port, your browser will assume you want port 80, since that's the default.  However, your web server isn't listening on port 80; it's listening on 8080.  Change `8080` in the two `listening` directives to `80`, and it should work as long as you don't already have another program on your server using that port.

Comment: it doesn't work. this is my firewall config in google cloud.  default-allow-http in http-server tcp:80 allow 1000 default

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip port number in URLs, expose your server on default ports.

For **http protocol, port 80** is default port.

For **https protocol, port 443** is default port.

So, expose your web server listen on either 80 or 443 as per protocol use.

Comment: I still can't use urls direction

Comment: this is my firewall config for 80

Comment: default-allow-http
in
http-server
tcp:80
allow
1000
default